# Mongo db query where condition for a column (list of values) having a value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I am trying to find a way to filter the records in Mongo db using Spring query.
Here is the scenario, let's see I have an Activity entity/document. One of the fields is a list of names. I want to see if I can get all the records that the names field includes get given value, let's say "Joker".

For example, my json in Mongo is

Activity 1 -

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52c14eb92f7ceb854e445354"),
  ...
  "names" : [{
      "username" : "username1",
      "realname" : "Super Man"
    }, {
      "username" : "username2",
      "realname" : "Iron Man"
    }]
}

Activity 2 -

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52c14eb92f7ceb854e445355"),
  ...
  "names" : [{
      "username" : "username3",
      "realname" : "Bat Man"
    }, {
      "username" : "username4",
      "realname" : "Joker"
    }]
}

And I expect the query will let me get Activity 2 only.

Also, if possible, I prefer to use spring Mongo query in my code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
db.collection.find({"names.realname": "Joker"});
```

I never used Spring query but should be something like

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("names.realname").is("Joker"));
List<MyClass> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: No way to do in the Spring Mongo query way? something like Criteria.where("xxx").is("yyy")? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thank you, @Graciano